# Transfering mp3 files from a remote server to the RPi via cronjob without overwriting

Tags: server, cron, script

I succeded in transfering files via ftp from a remote server to a raspberry,

```
#!/bin/bash -vx
ftp -in IP_SERVER<<END_SCRIPT
quote USER rem_user
quote PASS rem_pass
bin
prompt:off
cd /path_to_server_files
lcd /path_to_local_files
mget *.mp3
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

but there was a problem with ftp, which was overwriting the mp3 files everytime it ran a cronjob.

I have a company that provides background music to other companies. My method was leaving a computer in each one playing 24/7 or with other specific cronjobs, depending on the client. And the raspberry is a great way to do that instead a computer. The method i have right know that is working is a cronjob per folder. Each folder has a type of music. So i will be putting different music from time to time in the server and the cronjob will transfer those files once a week. It is set to transfer every mp3 file in that folder to the RPi. The thing is, it will transfer all the files there including the ones that were already there. If i put there, for example, 150 music files, it will take a long time transfering those, not to mention if it is done with all the folders since the RPi ARM is not that powerfull. The solution would be not overwriting the files already there, just the new ones. Then after some time another cronjob will delete all the files that have more than * days old.

I searched but it seems ftp doesnt have an option like this yet. So I found the wget command which allows to transfer without overwriting but i couldn't make it transfer multiple files. I have been trying to convert the script above with the wget command without success. Can someone with experience in this matter help out? it could be http also.
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:**

Tried to change mget with wget in the script but it returns `?invalid command`, tried to get ftp line out, the login credentials, nothing works. My problem is the conversion to wget, I have no idea how to do it. Probably i have to make a totally diferent script, hence this post.

**Some solution like this would solve the issue**

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4944295/wget-skip-if-files-exist

if it would be possible to convert the script to it, stopping the overwriting of files.

**SOLUTION - Thanks to ifermon I got this script working like a charm. Thanks for your impecable support and all the others who made efforts for this to work**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
from ftplib import FTP

local_path='/path_to_local_files/'
os.chdir(local_path)
ftp = FTP(host='server_name_or_IP',user='username', passwd='password')
ftp.cwd('/path_to_local_files/')
f_list = ftp.nlst()
for f in f_list:
if not f.endswith("mp3"):
  continue
new_f_name = local_path + f
if os.path.exists(new_f_name):
  continue
print("Copying remote file <{0}>to local file <{1}>".format(f,new_f_name))
ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ f, open(new_f_name,'wb').write)
```

you may need to install this in order for the script to work:

```
sudo apt-get install python-dev
```

Comment: Show us wget commands you've tried so far ? It will give us more idea why it is failing.

Comment: A few wget examples for getting an entire folder from an ftp. http://serverfault.com/questions/25199/using-wget-to-recursively-download-whole-ftp-directories

Comment: @dastaan I edited the question with the replie to your comment. Anything else you need let me know.

Comment: @dastaan I changed the script with this 
`#!/bin/bash -vx`
`wget -r --timestamp ftp://user:pass@ip /path_to_remote_files`
`bye`
`END_SCRIPT` 
Doesnt work, it shows a lot of errors. `command not found``bad port number` Can´t you give an example of how to put those commands in a script?

Comment: wget is not an ftp command, it's a shell command (vs. mget which stands for multiple get which is an ftp command).

Comment: @ifermon Thats the reason for not working using this script with ftp. Can´t you give sort of an example with wget inside a script to be executed with cron?

Comment: @angelfmf Why don't you break your problem into parts and deal with it one by one ? 1. First check if your `wget` command works on terminal. Is it able to fetch mp3 files from that folder. 2. Once sure that `wget` works, try using it with script. and like wise. Also by looking at your script, I assume that, `wget` command is not proper. There's no space between `ip` and `path` as far as i know. (and from examples given in shared link above)

Comment: @dastaan tried `wget -ar ftp://arcomedia:password@94.126.170.170/path to files/*  /local folder` didn't do anything, no errors either, but didn't transfer anything. Also I used without and with the space to and its the exact same result, same errors I showed in the above comment

Comment: @angelfmf That should work technically.I'm not sure why you used -a flag.

Comment: @dastaan I used -a to solve a scheme missing error: http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/wget-scheme-missing-869882/

Comment: No way you could use rsync instead of ftp?

Comment: @angelfmf That's -A.<format> option. Not -a. You should use -A.mp3 to solve that problem. Ie, your command should look like this `wget -A.mp3 -r ftp://arcomedia:password@94.126.170.170/path to files/* /path/to/local-folder`

Comment: @bobstro Already tried that, it was giving my a lot of trouble because of the ssh connection. Only got the files to transfer using ftp.

Comment: If you are doing this for a commercial/professional purpose, I'll be honest and say you are obviously in over your head with this in that context -- you need to hire or contract someone with experience on the operating system, preferably *network programming experience*.   I and others are happy to give bits of advice online, but that has its limitations; you cannot properly rebuild an engine or perform surgery by asking questions in a forum, period.   If you have paying customers, they are trusting you to do things in a rational, responsible way.

Comment: I am not the owner of this company, this is just an assignment given to me for my internship, so it is not my responsability. The main purpose here is to try to develop my knowledge about coding and help the company at the same time. Besides this topic is of interest to more RPi users, and if i could make it work, it could serve as other possibilities of using the raspberry. So this is more of an experiment that an actual business utility, if it wasn't this task would't be given to me, but to an expert like you said

Comment: Okay, so you are supposed to learn from this (and it sounds like you are).  Great.  In that case, keep in mind that this is off-topic here because the actual brand of computer is irrelevant -- it's the operating system that counts.  *You* will get more help with general linux questions on our larger sibling site [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/); if you decide to do this completely in code (e.g., python), which might be a good idea, general programming questions belong on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/)...

Comment: ..And please note I'm not trying to be a jerk with rules, I am trying to *teach* you something about how to learn.  As you've observed, ifermon is a bit unusual in his/her patience and willingness to help -- don't expect that from people every day.   This is the point of *learning* how to break a task down into parts and ask specific, independent questions *in the right place*, and it's why Stack Exchange is structured the way it is (and why it has been so successful with technical people)...

Comment: ..If this is where your future is, [take it to heart](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) (notice if you scroll down, that's been translated into 20+ languages).   I'm not saying you have done anything terribly wrong here, just some friendly advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wget is not an ftp command, it's a shell command (vs. mget which stands for multiple get which is an ftp command).

Probably a better way to do this is to use something like python. The below script logs into the server, looks for files ending in ".mp3", checks to see if the same file exists locally. If file does exist, it moves on to the next one. If it does not exist locally it copies it over.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import os
from ftplib import FTP

local_path='local directory name here'
os.chdir(local_path)
ftp = FTP(host='hostname', user='username', passwd='pwd')
ftp.cwd('remote directory name here')
f_list = ftp.nlst()
for f in f_list:
    if not f.endswith("mp3"):
        continue
    new_f_name = local_path + f
    if os.path.exists(new_f_name):
        continue
    print("Copying remote file <{0}> to local file <{1}>".format(f,
            new_f_name))
    ftp.retrbinary('RETR ' + f, open(new_f_name,'wb').write)
```

Save the above code to a file (e.g. get_mp3.py). Edit it to change paths to match your needed path. Make the file executable (e.g. chmod +x get_mp3.py). Then you can call it directly from a cron job. To install pysftp do the following:

You might have to install ftp first:

```
sudo apt-get install ftp
```

That's it. You should be good to go.

That should work, but it's not tested.

Comment: thanks for the reply but i don't understand exactly your answer. I have no experience with python, but i think i understood the main idea from answer. I will clarify what i have done with ftp wich is working. I have a website that runs music from a server using ftp. Each music type has a folder, like christmas theme, pop, smooth jazz, etc, and each one had a folder in which a script would be executed with cron from that type of music in the server to the folder of the same type in raspberry. Thats, why i need to transfer multiple files

Comment: because each folder will be getting lots of music from time to time. I understand that probably i had to use code language to do it but i was hoping to avoid it, since the problem with ftp was just the files being overwriting everytime. It would be best if there was comparison with the files from the server and the local ones and if they had the same name, not copying.

Comment: I added an example script that should get you 90% of the way there. Let me know if you need help with more specifics. Tested the python script and it does work.

Comment: Sorry the long wait, i have been trying to execute your solution, but i am stuck with the error: `/bin/sh: 1: /home/pi/Desktop/scripts_cron/get_mp3.py: not found` but it is there. I thought it could be due to permission, but after changing it from root to user, it stayed the same. I will try your other solution as well

Comment: I just noticed that you were thinking of downloading the mp3 files to diferent directories, but that would fill up the raspberry pi in an instant from diferent folders with the same mp3 music. That was just the issue i had with goldilocks solution. Isn't it possible to just not overwrite the music if the files have the same name?

Comment: Updated script to not copy file if it already exists. Regarding your can't find script problem - there has to be some issue with the path.  Using the command line, go into the scipts_cron directory and type 'pwd'. Copy that path and type 'crontab -e' . Modify the cron file to make sure the path is correct.

Comment: ok i changed it, but it says the same, i think it is weird. I checked the path like you said with `pwd` but it's correct. The problem is not in cron, if I try to execute the file directly it gives you something like "Failed to execute file get_mp3.py - Failed to execute child process /home/pi/Desktop/scripts_cron/get_mp3.py (no such file or directory)". Did some research on it, tried an update but nothing, still the same, i have no idea what it is causing it

Comment: It's linux territory, but 1. Validate that the python modules are installed. at the terminal, type 'python'. At the python prompt type import os <enter> then import pysftp <enter> .... if you get errors with either of those then you have an issue with the proper packages being installed. 2 - Validate that python is where I said it was. Exit the python interpreter (ctrl-d) and enter 'which python'... the result should be the same path that is in the first line of the script.  Let me know how it goes.

Comment: Ok i did what you said, the "local" folder was not in the actual path. After that i got an indentation block error. Put the spaces like you did on the code you provided and that solved it. But now i have these series of errors:

Comment: I put it in the question because it is too long to put here

Comment: Probably you need to install pycrypto: 'sudo pip install pycrypto' -- in general if you grep the last line of the error output you will get a result that will tell you what you need to install / do. You are not the first one to go down this path.

Comment: pycripto is not installing, its returning `GMP or MPIR library no found` and `Python.h: No such file or dir` erros. I installed an alternative from here: [https://community.gns3.com/thread/4583] but it has done nothing

Comment: Added line to my answer - install python-dev 'sudo apt-get install python-dev' - see if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25927/discussion-between-ifermon-and-angelfmf).

Answer (score 0):

First, use a timestamp to create a unique location:

```
#!/bin/bash

mp3dir=/path_to_local_files/$(date +%m-%d_%H:%M)
mkdir $mp3dir
cd $mp3dir
```

That `date` call will return something like `07-14_08:51`; there is an explanation of the format in `man date`, but that's month-day_hour:minute, where hour is 00-23, so unless you do this more than once per minute, it will always be unique.

Since you've now changed directory (`cd`) into that, you don't have to use `lcd` inside the `ftp` script:

```
ftp -in IP_SERVER<<END_SCRIPT
quote USER rem_user
quote PASS rem_pass
bin
prompt:off
cd /path_to_server_files
mget *.mp3
bye
END_SCRIPT
```

Done.  The mp3 files should all be in the `/path_to_local_files/07-14_08:51` (or whatever) directory.

Comment: Thanks goldilocks, i tried your solution and it works. There is an issue though. I set the cronjob to run every minute, and it creates a new folder every minute in that paste. That will end up filling the raspberry SD card. If  i put a folder to copy, for example, every monday at 1 a.m., at the end of the week, i would have several music folders, and the music wouldn't play automatically because the path to the files would be constantly changeing while the path in which the website gets the folders remains the same. Sorry if i wasn't clear enough. Is there to just prevent the overwriting?

Comment: There's always a way, although there is not always an easy way, lol -- but that is subjective. Anyway, it's not totally clear what you are doing; if the files that stand to be overwritten are always exactly the same (as opposed to being new versions of something with the same name), then you want to skip the download completely, right?  That means giving more specific instructions to `ftp` -- I suggest you ask about this on [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/), but describe in more detail exactly what you are trying to do and why.  There may be better tools around for this purpose.

Comment: For example: If you only want mp3's that are new on the server since the last time you checked, there might be a way to filter based on the timestamp of the files.   That's why the more relevant details you can provide, the more likely someone is to spot an appropriate solution.

Comment: I have updated the question clarifying what i need. Hope it is clearer now. It´s not that easy though because i am not english native, nor i have experience posting here. Anyway i will make a post at Unix & Linux like you suggested. I´d still be grateful if you could keep helping in this matter. Your solution was very close to what i needed. Like you said on your last comment i only want the new mp3's that are in the server yes. Do have more details about your solution related to the filteron the timestamp?

Comment: I don't use `ftp`, so it's hard for me to say.   What comes to mind is asking it for a list of what's currently on the server, then comparing that to the current download directory and downloading each file that isn't there specifically.  That means a bit of coding, in `bash` or whatever your preference is.  If you don't code, then hopefully there's a way to filter in this manner directly with `ftp`.

Comment: ...In fact looking at the `-nc` switch to `wget`, you could just feed that list to to it.

Comment: In fact i already tried that and also other flags, but i can't get wget to work. I've searched a lot for that matter but didn't find any straight answer, and i didn't fully understand how wget so it would be good if someone who worked with it could help. Ill post my last in here the most recent attempt with it, maybe u can stop whats wrong: `* * * * * usr/bin/wget -r -l1 -N -A.mp3 'http://servername/path_to_server_files' /var/www/rd/musica/teste/ftp11.log 2>&1`  But it keeps me giving 404 Not Found error and scheme missing on the local file path.

Comment: Based on your use of `ftp` before, you probably want to [include your username and password](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/wget-command-with-username-password/) and **use `ftp://`, not `http://`.**

Comment: Ok did exactly like you said, but it comes with the error: Bad Port Number from `ftp` until `path to files` and the other same error: Scheme missing